# App with React Native + Force React + WaterMelon DB

Tags: mobilesdk

I are trying to build react native app with 'forcereact', and it's working fine.
and then when we try to add Watermelon DB for offline data, it's not working.

these three are working together. If not what exact solution?

updated pod files according to https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB/issues/1285
still app not running after watermelonDB package added.

```
# Pod File


platform :ios, '14.0'

use_modular_headers!

project 'App.xcodeproj'
target 'App' do
  ....
  pod 'glog', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec', :modular_headers => false
  pod 'RCT-Folly', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec', :modular_headers => false
```

Error is: "Cannot find 'KeychainHelper' in scope"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please read [ask]. Questions about implementation problems need to include a specific description of the problem (including exact errors and stack traces, if any) and the code or metadata to reproduce the problem. Please limit code inclusions to only the relevant elements, such as an MVR (minimum viable reproduction).

Comment: these details more accurate, or still needs to update anything?